# determine the position of the variable value by counting character

Tags: python, position, character

I need to count the position of each variable value in the data frame. For example let's use this data frame:

## Create the DataFrame

```
data = {
    'ol': ['H_KXKnn1_01_p_lk0', 'H_KXKnn1_02_p_lk0', 'H_KXKnn1_03_p_lk0'],
    'nl': [12.01, 89.01, 25.01],
    'nol': ['Xn', 'Ln', 'Rn'],
    'nolp': [68, 70, 72],
    'nolxx': [0.0, 1.0, 5.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I am saving this data frame as .dat

```
df.to_csv('your_file.dat', sep='\t', index=False)
```

When I count the position where each value character starts and ends in the .dat file I would have:

```
variable position (start,end)
ol        (0,17)
nl        (18,23)
nol       (24,26)
nolp      (27,29)
nolxx     (30,33)
```

I am considering the "_", ".", and space as character as well. However when I run this code that iterate over each column:

```
for col in df.columns:
    col_length = df[col].astype(str).apply(len).max() + df[col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.count('_') + x.count('.')).max()
    positions[col] = (current_pos, current_pos + col_length - 1)
    current_pos += col_length + 1

positions_df = pd.DataFrame(list(positions.items()), columns=['Variable', 'Position'])
```

it returns the following values:

```
  Variable    Position
      ol      (0, 20)
      nl     (22, 27)
     nol     (29, 30)
    nolp     (32, 33)
   nolxx     (35, 38)
```

I am not sure why it is returning different numbers/position. Any help how I can do that is very welcome! Thank you!!

Comment: 17 characters + 4 `_` - 1 = 20. Why do you think your code will give 17?

Comment: Why are you adding the number of `_` and `.` characters? They're already included in the length of the value.

Comment: Then 21 + 1 = 22. Then 22 + 5 + 1 - 1 = 27.  That output seems to match the formulas to me.

Comment: Using this value as an example "H_KXKnn1_01_p_lk0" considering each "_" as a character, there are 17 in the total. Then the space between "ol" and "nl" the next value starts at position 18, because I am considering each space as a character. If I don't add the "_" and "." in the code it gives me lower characters, for example ol (0,12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of all strings in first column is `17`. You are adding an additional value to it that makes the result different. Since you have 3 `'_'`'s in the string, it becomes 17 + 3 = 20.

```
df[col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.count('_') + x.count('.')
```

Here is the modified version of your code that produces the same output as you get from your first code :

```
positions = {}
current_pos = 0

for col in df.columns:
    col_length = df[col].astype(str).apply(len).max()
    positions[col] = (current_pos, current_pos + col_length)
    current_pos += col_length + 1

positions_df = pd.DataFrame(list(positions.items()), columns=['Variable', 'Position'])
```

And here is the output :

```
 Variable  Position
0       ol   (0, 17)
1       nl  (18, 23)
2      nol  (24, 26)
3     nolp  (27, 29)
4    nolxx  (30, 33)
```